# Edit meta property value in Open Graph meta tag

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-seomatic

I would like to implement [Pinterest Product Pin](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/rich-pins/products/?) for my products. I need to update og:xxx values. Here is how i done:

```
{% set og = seomaticMeta.og %}
{% set og = og | merge({'type': "product", 'product:price:currency': "USD", 'product:price:amount': variant.price|number_format(2) }) %}
{% set seomaticMeta = seomaticMeta | merge({'og': og}) %}
```

This adds new tags but the property of the meta tag should not include 'og:' in product related meta tag. So this outputs something like:

```
<meta property="og:product:price:amount" content="300.00" />
```

but it should be something like this:

```
<meta property="product:price:amount" content="300.00" />
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Right now, SEOmatic assumes an `og:` namespace for all OpenGraph tags, which clearly isn't correct. So you'd just need to add these tags yourself if you want to use them.